# $wpdb is get_results escaped

Tags: wpdb, security

I'm guessing the answer is no here, but wanted to be sure.  I would expect that when I get a database object or array using get_results that I still need to add htmlspecialchars() or esc_html() when placing the output in HTML.  I did look at the function, but it's not really clear without finding functions that the get_results function uses (and not sure how deep I would need to dig).  This question brings up one very small other question.  Any reason to use the WordPress function esc_html() over the generic htmlspecialchars()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: of course they are not - otherwise you couldn’t use them to save them in DB.

But... the answer to your question isn’t so easy.

**Sanitizing** is a process of preparing data for storing in DB. So for example if you insert some illegal characters in post_name, then it will be removed, so the post_name is sanitized, before saving. If you use color picker in Customizer, then you should sanitize it (checking if it really is a color and not some random string) before saving. And so on.

But sanitized data can still be dangerous. You can use “>” character in title, so title containing it will be sanitized. But of course you can’t print it in HTML of your code.

That’s where **escaping** joins the game. Escaping is a process of making data from DB secure for HTML code (based on context). Remember that the same title should be escaped in a different way when it’s printed inside  tag (then you should use `esc_html`), than when it’s used as html attribute (you should use `esc_attr`) and so on.

So yes - you should always sanitize your data before storing it in DB and always use correct way of escaping based on given context.

Comment: Appreciate that.  So it is not escaped in any way when retrieving from the database (that's the part I was mostly interested in).

Comment: @tim92109 No, it’s not.

Comment: so how did you made it so that it returns the data as i have saved it? pre-sanitizing ? without itering over every column in every result in my entire project ?