# how to execute different sql query in non-sanitized $wpdb->get_results function

Tags: wpdb, sql

I saw `$wpdb->get_results` that function is not sanitized by core code([$wpdb is get_results escaped](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/305879/wpdb-is-get-results-escaped)).

For example, in following code

```
$wpdb->get_results( "DELETE FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'likeiwould' AND `meta_value` = '{$array['item']}'" );
```

That should execute a mysql sleep command, but not working.

```
$array['item'] = "123';SELECT+sleep(10)'"
```

Result:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'likeiwould' AND `meta_value` = '123';SELECT+sleep(10)''
```

So, if `$wpdb->get_results` is not sanitized by core code, why we can't execute different sql query in it? Thanks.

Comment: "That should execute a mysql sleep command" - try the generated SQL query in phpMyAdmin or MySQL command line interface - do you get any results, or does the query results in an (unknown) error? But really, why would you want to execute vulnerable SQL queries? And always sanitize user-supplied data or data from unknown/untrusted sources; e.g. use `$wpdb->prepare()`.

Comment: Hey @SallyCJ I got it why it's not working, `get_results` function not working when you give multiple SQL queries after semicolon `;` and also adding backslashes after quotes `'`, `"`. It was experimental situation now is okay, thank for the response.

Comment: Ah my bad, sorry for the confusion, I completely misunderstood the actual question.. :p But I hope my answer helps you? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if `$wpdb->get_results` is not sanitized by core code, why we can't execute different SQL query in it?

Because the [`wpdb` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) uses (see [`wpdb::_do_query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/_do_query/) ) [`mysqli_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) (by default) or [`mysql_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), and unfortunately these functions **do not support multiple queries** such as `SELECT <query>; INSERT <query>; SELECT <query>`.

Therefore, if you want to execute multiple SQL queries using `wpdb`, you would need to execute each query individually like so:

```php
// You cannot do this:
// And I mean, regardless the query is escaped/safe or not, this won't work.
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT <query>; INSERT <query>; SELECT <query>" ); // doesn't work

// But you can do this:
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT <query>" );
$rows = $wpdb->query( "INSERT <query>" ); // this works, but you should use $wpdb->insert(), though
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT <query>" );
```

And in reply to your comment:

> `get_results` function not working when you give multiple SQL queries after semicolon `;` and also adding backslashes after quotes `'`, `"`

About that "semicolon `;`" (e.g. as in `DELETE <query>; SELECT <query>`), yes you're correct.

And about that "adding backslashes", yes, you're also correct, but the better/preferred way is to use `wpdb::prepare()` to prepare the SQL query for safe execution.

```php
// We used the same query, but different data.

// Query 1: Not escaped, but data is good, so no errors thrown.
$value = '"Foo"'; // intentionally not escaped
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = '{$value}' LIMIT 2" );
// Generated SQL: SELECT ID, post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = '"Foo"' LIMIT 2

// Query 2: Not escaped, data is bad, thus results in a syntax error!
$value = "'Foo'"; // intentionally not escaped
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = '{$value}' LIMIT 2" );
// Generated SQL: SELECT ID, post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = ''Foo'' LIMIT 2

// Query 3: Works good - data escaped manually, and no errors thrown.
$value = '\'Foo\''; // backslashes added manually
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = '{$value}' LIMIT 2" );
// Generated SQL: SELECT ID, post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = '\'Foo\'' LIMIT 2

// Query 4: Works good - data not escaped, but wpdb::prepare() is used, so no errors thrown.
$value = "'Foo'"; // intentionally not escaped
// But then, this query uses wpdb::prepare().
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = %s LIMIT 2", $value ) );
// Generated SQL: SELECT ID, post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = '\'Foo\'' LIMIT 2
```

### Notes

1. `wpdb` uses `mysql_query()` if the MySQLi functions are not available or if the WordPress constant named `WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL` is defined.
2. MySQLi has support for [multiple statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php) using [`mysqli_multi_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php), but (as of writing), `wpdb` does *not* use that function.